# Python FastAPI error when I test my endpoint on POSTMAN

Tags: python, fastapi, rate-limiting, rate

I am trying to create a rate limiting for my API, I am using this approach.
But when I run the endpoint on POSTMAN, it does not work. It gives me Internal Server Error

`TypeError: RateLimiterMiddleware.__call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'app' INFO:     127.0.0.1:53544 - "POST /battery HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error`

The error above is what I am getting and I only get this error when I test the endpoint on POSTMAN

I have tried everything I can but it is not working. I have a middleware.py, another file for eeping request counts and my main.py where I have all my endpoints.

This is my middleware.py where the function I am having the issues is

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, HTTPException
from typing import Callable, Any
from request_counter import RequestCounter
from starlette.requests import Request
import time


class RateLimiterMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, app: FastAPI, max_requests: int, window_seconds: int, request_counter: RequestCounter):
        self.app = app
        self.request_counter = request_counter
        self.max_requests = max_requests
        self.window_seconds = window_seconds

    async def __call__(self, request: Request, call_next: Callable[[Request], Any]):
        client_ip = request.client.host
        current_time = time.time()

        request_count = self.request_counter.check_rate_limit(
            client_ip, current_time, self.window_seconds, self.max_requests)
        if request_count >= self.max_requests:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=429, detail="Too Many Requests")

        self.request_counter.increase_request_count(
            client_ip, current_time, self.window_seconds)
        return await call_next(request)
```

This below is where I am keeping request count

```
from fastapi import HTTPException


class RequestCounter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.request_counts = {}

    def increase_request_count(self, client_ip, current_time, window_seconds):
        timestamp = int(current_time - window_seconds)

        if client_ip not in self.request_counts:
            self.request_counts[client_ip] = {}

        if timestamp not in self.request_counts:
            self.request_counts[timestamp] = 0

        self.request_counts[client_ip][timestamp] += 1

    def check_rate_limit(self, client_ip, current_time, window_seconds, max_requests):
        timestamp = int(current_time - window_seconds)

        if client_ip not in self.request_counts or timestamp not in self.request_counts[client_ip]:
            return 0

        request_count = self.request_counts[client_ip][timestamp]
        if request_count >= max_requests:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=429, detail="Too Many Requests")

        return request_count
```

This is my main.py

```
from config import init_firebase
from firebase_admin import firestore
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from models import Battery
from typing import List
from middleware import RateLimiterMiddleware
from request_counter import RequestCounter


init_firebase()

app = FastAPI()

db = firestore.client()


request_counter = RequestCounter()
rate_limiter_middleware = RateLimiterMiddleware(
    app, max_requests=10, window_seconds=60, request_counter=request_counter)

app.add_middleware(rate_limiter_middleware)


@app.post("/battery/", response_model=Battery)
async def create_battery(battery: Battery):
    try:
        doc_ref = db.collection("batteries").document()
        doc_ref.set(battery.model_dump())
        return {**battery.model_dump(), "id": doc_ref.id}
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))


@app.get("/batteries/", response_model=List[Battery])
async def get_batteries():
    try:
        ref = db.collection("batteries")
        batteries = ref.stream()

        battery_list = []

        for battery in batteries:
            data = battery.to_dict()
            battery_list.append(data)
        return battery_list
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
```

Comment: Your python console should show the actual error/exception that happens unless you're catching it and swallowing it without actually printing anything (i.e. the `except Exception as e:` part - there is no need to have the try/except wrapper here, as that would be the default behavior of the controller regardless. You only end up hiding the actual stacktrace in your console that allows you to debug it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FastAPI.add_middleware()` is intherited from [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/) which [accepts it's own middleware classes](https://www.starlette.io/middleware/#pure-asgi-middleware). You need to use `app.middleware("http")(rate_limiter_middleware)` instead (`FastAPI`'s middleware decorator) to make it work

Comment: I do not really get the explanation here. Please can you explain better so I can understand. If you can in details, I will really appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: @AbiodunBankole `add_middleware()` expects a subclass of `BaseHTTPMiddleware` (you can read about those via provided docs link) whereas you are passing a callable with signature identical to [FastAPI's own way of creating middleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/#create-a-middleware) so you need to use @app.middleware("http") or wrap a function directly

Comment: I understand now, thank you and I have been able to resolve it. But I notice my count does not go beyond 2, I specified 1 initially and added an increment if request already exist. But when it increases to 2 it goes back to start counting again from 1.